# How to remove all leading space while copying table from excel to word

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-word-2013

I have several tables generated in microsoft excel 2013. Now I want to paste these tables into ms word 2013 but the problem arises when I paste these tables. The tables are pasted well but with some leading space before each cell in the table in the ms word as below.I tried with the trim functtion in excel but with vain.
I need to delete those spaces.Those tables in Excel get updated frequently by manual calculation. So I need a hassle free way to removing spaces.

[image: demo error]

Comment: Use search/replace with a [regular expression](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Find-and-replace-text-and-other-data-in-a-Word-document-c6728c16-469e-43cd-afe4-7708c6c779b7?CorrelationId=8abcd39c-dbf4-483c-bf22-419e47c6f470&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&ocmsassetID=HA102350661)

Answer (score 1):

Select the table and run this below macro code

```
Sub NoSpaces()
    Dim c As Range

    For Each c In Selection.Cells
        c = Replace(c, " ", "")
    Next
End Sub
```

write this code in the module and run using immediate window. worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the "trim" function [link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TRIM-function-410388fa-c5df-49c6-b16c-9e5630b479f9), because "replace" replaces any space also in the middle of a string: e.g. ".L.NP" gives "LNP" and not "L.NP" as desired.